# Android change data in Firebase database after turn off internet connection

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an application which is using Firebase. I want to change some field in database(online status of user) from true to false when user turn off internet connection(data or wifi). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/OnDisconnect is the function you need to check out.  It tells the server what to do when a client disconnects

Comment: Thanks a lot for help :)

Comment: No worries!  Feel free to upvote/accept the answer if it fits your needs.  (welcome to SO too. :D)